# Why is this SVG with css animation being cropped only on Firefox?

Tags: html, jquery, css, svg

In the hero section of this webpage is an SVG that is being animated using CSS. Only on Firefox the SVG has been cropped. I do not know why this is happening. I tried with Jquery to force the size of the SVG to the height and width of the window with this code which was advised on another question. It didn't work.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.hero-animated').attr("width", window.innerWidth).attr("height",window.innerHeight)
});
```

https://umweltpaket-berlin-mitte.de/

Comment: We'll need a [mcve]. I don't think anyone's going to go through an entire website to find a problem.

Comment: @RobertLongson it is not the entire website, it is just the hero SVG animation as stated in the question. If I was to create a reproducible example, there is no guarantee the issue will occur again. It is a very specific problem.

Comment: And if the external website changes, this question, and any answers, will then become useless to future readers. That's why Stack Overflow insists on not linking to sites that are likely to change.

Answer (score 0):

In the SVG code itself there was masks which were cropping the svg elements, I removed these manually and it worked. Similar to this: mask="url(#mask-12)"